# How to wrap a flash animation into a div?

Tags: jquery, css, flash, twitter-bootstrap, animation

I am trying to add a flash animation to my website. 
I am using bootstrap 2.3.2.

I added my flash animation inside my div with swfobject

```
<div class="span12 fill">
    <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="100%" height="100%" id="myFlashContent" style="visibility: visible;">
        <param name="movie" value="img/anime1.swf">
        <!--[if !IE]>-->
            <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="img/anime1.swf" width="100%" height="100%">
            <!--<![endif]--> <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">
                            <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player">
                        </a>

            <!--[if !IE]>-->
            </object>
        <!--<![endif]-->
    </object>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.fill {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

I added this .**fill class** in order to get the full height. Normally since this is twitter bootstrap, it must have been set to full-height. But I couldn't get it.

Normally it must be shown as this [image]

However, the right side of the animation **overflows** to the right.

[image]

This is my animation url

http://www.carantina.com/img/anime1.swf

This is my website url for demo purposes

http://www.carantina.com/hangar-kapisi

Comment: Can you show your CSS too?

Comment: You added the '.fill' class? Where in your HTML is this element that has the fill class#

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure if this is the solution you're looking for but you can control overflow using the CSS overflow property. If you're only interested in horizontal overflow then you can use overflow-x.

```
overflow-x: auto;
```

Will display a horizontal scrollbar if scrolling is required.